# Close game addons when the game closes

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm playing Path of Exile with a few addons. With the help of this forum I've written a script that starts all the addons and then the game, with a single batch file. Now I'd also like for it to close all the addons when the game closes. I'm open to using PowerShell, I just don't know how. I also don't know how to translate what I've already written into PowerShell. The code is below. Thank you!

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------

::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW:
runas /noprofile /user:CARLOSDESKTOP\resur /savecred "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\Exiled Presence v1.0.5\Exiled-Presence.exe"
runas /noprofile /user:CARLOSDESKTOP\resur /savecred "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\poe-overlay\poe-overlay.exe"
cd /d "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\Awakened PoE Trade"
start "" "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\Awakened PoE Trade\Awakened PoE Trade.exe"
cd /d "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\Autoflask"
start "" "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\Autoflask\PoEAutoFlask.ahk"
cd /d "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\POE-Trades-Companion-dev"
start "" "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\Addons\POE-Trades-Companion-dev\POE Trades Companion.ahk"
cd /d "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE"
start "" "C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE\PathOfExile_x64.exe"
```

Comment: Find the process Id and names associated with the executables using Get-Process then stop them using Stop-Process.
It's doubtful you're going to find someone to translate your code into PS as that's really not what this site is for. Have go yourself then post code here if you get stuck.

Comment: @Scepticalist, Thanks for the reply! Is Stop-Process a batch command or a PowerShell command? :)

Comment: There should generally be no need to change directory just to run executable files. Why does your game require to be elevated? If it really is necessary, as you're already using AHK, why not try [`RunAsTask()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=4334) instead of vbscript. How do you close your addons without command line? or can you not run addons unless you do so via the command line. If the latter, why would somebody develop addons for a game, which require starting via command line, but which do not end with the game they're for? Don't the addons have 'close' command options?

Comment: @Compo Hello, and thanks for the reply as well. 

The addons can all be started manually (exe/.ahk files), and closed manually from the task tray (right click to exist each one). I was just fiddling around hoping for a way to make this all more seamless. 

Re: elevation, to be honest I don't know what everything above "::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW:" does, I just copied it from another forum and it worked. Some of the addons work better with admin rights.

The game doesn't need admin rights. I've removed starting the game through the batch file given some inconsistencies I've found.

Comment: Running your game elevated is effectively giving your game privileges higher that of a standard user, effectively giving the game administrator access to your system. I do not believe that should be necessary, and it it were, your game should not be trusted. If you got rid of that rubbish, you shouldn't need to use `runas` and would only really need to change your working directory to `"C:\Games (C SSD)\PoE"` then run six executables, the first two in sequence, (directly), then the next four in parallel, (using `start`). What you'd have was a simple seven line batch-file instead of thirty six.